# How do I Serialize/Deserialize multiple same class instances spread across an assembly

Tags: c#

The following Console window code illustrates my problem of trying to Desrialize multiple same class instances across the same assembly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string fnam = "MyFile.bin";
        Dummy a = new Dummy();
        Dummy b = a;

        Console.WriteLine($"a == b {a == b}"); // true

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(fnam, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, b);
        stream.Close();

        stream = new FileStream(fnam, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        a = (Dummy)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        b = (Dummy)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        Console.WriteLine($"a == b {a == b}"); // false

        File.Delete(fnam);
    }
}
[Serializable]
class Dummy { }
```

To emphasize, I need the duplicate class instances to be Deserialized accordingly.

Comment: `Deserialize` won't care if the original references pointed to the same object or not when `Serialize` was explicity called - you will end up with two disctinct objects afterwards

Comment: Thought that there wouldn't be a way round this. Thankyou.